# limit and absolute absolute value problem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, absolute-value

$$\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{2-|x|}{2+x}$$

If I calculate the left and right-hand limit I get different results.

Left hand side:
$$\lim_{x \to -2^-}\frac{2+x}{2+x}=1$$

Right hand side: $$\lim_{x \to -2^+} \frac{2-x}{2+x}=\text{undefined}$$

My question is that my procedure is right or wrong?

Comment: I get a solution from an unauthorized source what explains that it is 1

Comment: Note that the modulus function is not continuous at $0$, but it is around a neighborhood of $-2$, hence you could compute the limit simply assuming $|x|=-x$.

Answer (score 6):

Since $x \to -2$, we can assume that $x < 0$ so that $|x| = -x$.

Then $$\frac{2-|x|}{2+x} = \frac{2+x}{2+x} = 1 \xrightarrow{x \to -2} 1$$
so the limit exists and it is equal to $1$.

Answer (score 3):

When $x$ is near $-2$ approaching it from the left, $2+x$ is equivalent to $2-|x|$ (if $x<0$, then $x=-|x|$):

$$
\lim_{x\to-2^-}\frac{2-|x|}{2+x}=\lim_{x\to-2^-}\frac{2-|x|}{2-|x|}=\lim_{x\to-2^-}1=1.
$$

When $x$ is near $-2$ approaching it from the right, $2+x$ also seems to be equivalent to $2-|x|$:

$$
\lim_{x\to-2^+}\frac{2-|x|}{2+x}=\lim_{x\to-2^+}\frac{2-|x|}{2-|x|}=\lim_{x\to-2^+}1=1.
$$

Since both one-sided limits are equal to the same number, the limit exists and is equal to $1$:

$$\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{2-|x|}{2+x}=1.$$

Even though the function itself is undefined at $x=-2$ because the denominator at that point is zero ($f(-2)=\frac{2-|-2|}{2-2}=\frac{0}{0}$), the limit of this function at $x=-2$ does exist and is equal to $1$.

Comment: When x is near −2 approaching it from the right, 2+x also seems to be equivalent to 2−|x| ...sorry, I don't get it

Comment: I get it. you are amazing to explain

Answer (score 3):

Multiply and divide by $2+|x|$ and cancel:
$$\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{2-|x|}{2+x}=\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{4-x^2}{(2+x)(2+|x|)}=\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{2-x}{2+|x|}=\frac{2-(-2)}{2+2}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-2}\frac{2-|x|}{2+x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow-2}\frac{2+x}{2+x}=1.$$

Comment: it occurs when you consider right hand side limit I mean x  if x>0  and Left hand side limit  -x if x<0

Comment: @Jobiar Hossain Since $x\rightarrow-2$, we can assume that $x<0$ because for $x\geq0$ it's not interesting.

Comment: yes, but why do we not consider left hand side and right hand side limit ? I know this idea but it don't give information about left hand side limit and right hand side limit.

Comment: @Jobiar Hossain $x\rightarrow-2$. Id est, it's interesting what happens around $-2$, id est, for $x<0$. If $x\rightarrow-2$ so can be $x>-2$ and can be $x<-2$ by the definition of the limits. We don't need to consider two cases here.

Comment: If you draw the graph, you will find that there is a vertical Asymptote at x=-2

Comment: @Jobiar Hossain Which says that there is mistake in your graph. $(-2,1)$ is the hole.

Comment: I think your wrong reasoning is the following. $2-|x|=2-x$ for $x\geq0$ and $2-|x|=2+x$ for $x<0$. You think about $x>-2$ as $x>0,$ which is not true.

Answer (score 1):

What about L'Hospital's Rule?

Since

$$\frac{2-|-2|}{2+-2}=\frac{0}{0}$$

then

$$\frac{d}{dx}(2-|x|)=-\frac{x}{|x|}, \frac{d}{dx}(2+x)=1$$

evaluate 
$\frac{-\frac{x}{|x|}}{1}$ 
at $x=-2$
yields

$$\frac{-\frac{-2}{|-2|}}{1} = \frac{-(-1)}{1}=1$$